# Cleaning up a one file project

Tags: java, android, code-cleanup

So I'm working on a project and am using a lot of code or atleast a decent amount all in one file and am wondering if there is a way to clean it up into multiple files. I've only every worked with single file. So when It come to adding more files I'm not really sure how to go about this so I'm gonna ask for help on cleaning up the project. the ideal outcome is to have it more understandable via small chunks in other files to clean up the CoreActivity. or if you see a way to clean up some code into a easier and less exhaustive way of writing it then do fix

CoreActivity.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.github.pwittchen.gesture.library.Gesture;
import com.github.pwittchen.gesture.library.GestureListener;
import com.github.pwittchen.swipe.library.rx2.Swipe;
import com.github.pwittchen.swipe.library.rx2.SwipeListener;

 public class CoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Widgets
ConstraintLayout m_Preference_Toolbar;
ConstraintLayout m_Toolbar;
ConstraintLayout m_Preferences;

EditText m_WebView_Search;
WebView m_WebView;

private Swipe WebSwipe;
private Gesture WebGesture;

//Variables
String Url = "https://www.Google.ca";
int WebS =0;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_core);


    //Find Views
    m_Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.m_Toolbar);
    m_Preferences = findViewById(R.id.m_Preferences);
    m_WebView_Search = findViewById(R.id.m_WebView_Search);
    m_WebView = findViewById(R.id.m_WebView);
    m_Preference_Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.m_Preferences_Toolbar);

    m_Preference_Toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    m_Preferences.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        Animation ToolbarGone,ToolbarPrefVisible;
        int x = 0;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            m_Preferences.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            x =1;

            ToolbarGone = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CoreActivity.this, R.anim.m_toolbar_gone);
            m_Toolbar.startAnimation(ToolbarGone);

            if(m_Preferences.getVisibility() == View.GONE || x == 1) {
                ToolbarPrefVisible = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CoreActivity.this, R.anim.m_preference_toolbar_appear);
                m_Preference_Toolbar.startAnimation(ToolbarPrefVisible);
            }
          return false;
        }
    });


    //m_WebView
    final WebSettings m_WebViewSetting = m_WebView.getSettings();
    m_WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    m_WebViewSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    m_WebViewSetting.setSupportZoom(true);
    m_WebViewSetting.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    m_WebViewSetting.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    m_WebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");
    m_WebView.loadUrl(Url); //Default HomePage




    //m_WebView_Search TextView and Keyboard
    m_WebView_Search.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                if (m_WebView_Search.getText().toString().contains(".com")
                        || m_WebView_Search.getText().toString().contains(".ca")
                        || m_WebView_Search.getText().toString().contains(".net")
                        || m_WebView_Search.getText().toString().contains(".org")) {
                    Url = m_WebView_Search.getText().toString();
                    m_WebView.loadUrl("https://www." + Url);
                    m_WebView_Search.clearFocus();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(m_WebView_Search.getWindowToken(), 0);
                } else {
                    if (m_WebView_Search.getText().toString().contains("")) {
                        Url = m_WebView_Search.getText().toString();
                        m_WebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.ca/search?q=" + Url);
                        m_WebView_Search.clearFocus();
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(m_WebView_Search.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    //Swipe Events WebSwipe
    WebSwipe = new Swipe(350, 700);

    WebSwipe.setListener(new SwipeListener() {
        int Web = 0;
        Animation WebShrink, WebEnlarge;
        @Override
        public void onSwipingLeft(final MotionEvent event) {
            if(m_WebView.canGoForward()){
                m_WebView.goForward();
            }
            else{
                m_WebView.reload();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipedLeft(final MotionEvent event) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipingRight(final MotionEvent event) {
            if(m_WebView.canGoBack()){
                m_WebView.goBack();
            }
            else{
                m_WebView.reload();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipedRight(final MotionEvent event) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipingUp(final MotionEvent event) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipedUp(final MotionEvent event) {
            //WebView Animation (Enlarge)
            if(Web == 0){
                  WebEnlarge = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CoreActivity.this, R.anim.m_webview_enlarge);
                m_WebView.startAnimation(WebEnlarge);
                Web = 1;

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        m_Toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }, 350);
            }
        }

            @Override
        public void onSwipingDown(final MotionEvent event) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipedDown(final MotionEvent event) {
            //WebView Animation (Shrink)
            if(Web == 1){
                WebShrink = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CoreActivity.this,R.anim.m_webview_shrink);
                m_WebView.startAnimation(WebShrink);
                m_Preference_Toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Web = 0;
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        m_Toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }, 350);
            }
        }
    });

    WebGesture = new Gesture();
    WebGesture.addListener(new GestureListener() {
        @Override public void onPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        }

        @Override public void onTap(MotionEvent motionEvent) {


            }

        @Override public void onDrag(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        }

        @Override public void onMove(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        }

        @Override public void onRelease(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        }

        @Override public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        }

        @Override public void onMultiTap(MotionEvent motionEvent, int clicks) {
        }
    });
}

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent (MotionEvent event){
        WebSwipe.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        WebGesture.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: you could learn oo, but it's not as if your codebase is that extended.

Comment: A good way of thinking, when it comes to reduce and split up code, is to answer the following question: How can have maintain a single level of abstraction throughout my class. What I mean is: suppose you're working on something such as a PDF File, in which you have the Document, the paragraphs and the words. These are three different levels of abstraction and I will try to have at least 3 methods or classes to handle them. So try and think the same way to find how to split your code

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to split code is to think about Single Responsibility (as per the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles).

As an example in your code, your touch listener can be separated. This would entail making a class that extended the touch listener's class (`View.OnTouchListener`) instead of extending an activity.

This block in your code:

```
m_Preferences.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    ...
});
```

Would become **MyTouchListener.java**:

```
public class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    Animation ToolbarGone,ToolbarPrefVisible;
    int x = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        ... // keep exactly your same code here
    }

}
```

And then your activity gets changed to:

```
m_Preferences.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
```

Comment: Doing this how would I call on in form the main to use the class

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking